# How to suppress Apple linker warnings about conflict architecture?

Tags: linker, universal-binary, apple-clang

My program is compiled as universal binary, and its x86_64 part uses Intel IPP library. During the final linking stage, Apple Clang's linker raises thousands of warning messages about object files in IPP static library is in x86_64 and don't have arm64 part (surely it is). I have tried to suppress it using `-no_arch_warnings` linker option, but the linker says this option has been obsoleted. How to suppress these warnings nowadays?